# What is the recommended way to package up a C# Class Library (DLL)?

Tags: c#, packaging

I am creating a C# class library for use by other developers.  How should I package it up - just zip up the DLL and put it on the website?

Comment: Tip: Package it with a working, simple C# example (i.e. have an additional project inside the library's solution with an example).  Your users will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to upload the code source including build scripts to a web site such as [googlecode](http://code.google.com/intl/bg-BG/) so that other developers could download it and compile it but if it is closed source library zipping the assembly (mylibrary.DLL), documentation (mylibrary.XML) and debug information file (mylibrary.PDB) should be enough.

Comment: If it's closed source, I'm not sure that you'd ship the XML and PDB files.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a DLL then I wouldn't bother zipping it.  However it would be nice if you did zip up some documentation with it along with a sample configuration file if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you ever used another third party one? What would you like to see in the perfectly packaged third party download?

I'd zip it up with the following in at a minimum:

- your dll in a /bin/ folder
- readme (txt or html) explaining what it is, how to install and where to get more info

if you are including the source then
* source in /source/ folder
* Any tests in a /tests/ folder

If its something good you might want to stick it up on google code or codeplex rather than your own site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You should include documentation in your ZIP file, including a link back to your website.  NDoc is great for generating documentation from your XML comments.

Answer (score 0):

Look at 3rd party prijects for inspiration, but yes, a zipped dll is fine.

If your documentation is large then you should put it into a separate zip, and if your releasing the source you should put that into a 3rd zip.

Either way your dll should comes with a readme describing what version it is, what the purpose is, who wrote it and how to get in touch with them, along with any dependencies or other useful snippets of information.

Documentation is really important!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, if this is a product, you would want a setup project that installs it.  This would include placing it in the GAC and leaving documentation somewhere.

*edit*

Just to clarify, I mean real documentation, not just what's automatically generated from comments.